# How to filter blog posts with multiple categories in octobercms?

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-plugins, octobercms-backend

In October CMS how to filter blog posts with multiple categories? I'm using RainLab Blog plugin. The plugin only allows filtering with one category. I want a combined result. Please help.

Comment: i would suggest `coding it manually` as plugin is not come with this function `out of the box`, so you can use `blog-plugin` components for the reference and add your own component to your plugin which can do this .. if you find any difficulties in that we can solve that.. as to make this functionality avail it requires quite effort and code so we can not post whole thing here rather we can help you in small chunks so you get what you expected. just start it we will help you through out whole process

Answer (score 3):

You will need to use some custom code to filter based on multiple categories. If still using the PostList component, make the following changes and you will be able to filter the list based on multiple categories.

What I have done below is modified the PostList component, first by forking it and replacing the `posts` variable with the `filteredPosts` variable. Then, to set the `filteredPosts`, the code was written to get all the blog posts and return only those which contained the categories in `$categories` array. *Admittedly, this method is definitely not the most efficient and could be further improved*

1. Add the PostList component to the page
2. Add the following code in the *Mark Up*

   ```
   <ul class="post-list">
       {% for post in filteredPosts %}
       <li>
           <h3><a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></h3>

           <p class="info">
               Posted
               {% if post.categories.count %} in {% endif %}
               {% for category in post.categories %}
                   <a href="{{ category.url }}">{{ category.name }}</a>{% if not loop.last %}, {% endif %}
               {% endfor %}
               on {{ post.published_at|date('M d, Y') }}
           </p>

           <p class="excerpt">{{ post.summary|raw }}</p>
       </li>
   {% else %}
       <li class="no-data">{{ noPostsMessage }}</li>
   {% endfor %}
   </ul>

   {% if posts.lastPage > 1 %}
       <ul class="pagination">
           {% if posts.currentPage > 1 %}
               <li><a href="{{ this.page.baseFileName|page({ (pageParam): (posts.currentPage-1) }) }}">&larr; Prev</a></li>
           {% endif %}

           {% for page in 1..posts.lastPage %}
               <li class="{{ posts.currentPage == page ? 'active' : null }}">
                   <a href="{{ this.page.baseFileName|page({ (pageParam): page }) }}">{{ page }}</a>
               </li>
           {% endfor %}

          {% if posts.lastPage > posts.currentPage %}
               <li><a href="{{ this.page.baseFileName|page({ (pageParam):(posts.currentPage+1) }) }}">Next &rarr;</a></li>
           {% endif %}
       </ul>
   {% endif %}
   ```
3. Add the following code in the *Code* tab of the CMS. To change the

   ```
   use RainLab\Blog\Models\Post as BlogPost;

   function onStart(){
       //This is where you list the categories you want to display
       $categories = ['cat-a','cat-b'];
       $posts = [];
       foreach(BlogPost::all() as $blog){
           foreach($blog->categories as $cat){
               if(in_array($cat->slug, $categories)) {
                   array_push($posts, $blog);
                   break;
               }
           }
       }
      $this['filteredPosts'] = $posts;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 3):

First solution:

In the Code tab of the CMS page:

```
use RainLab\Blog\Models\Post as BlogPost;

function onStart(){    

       $this['filteredPosts'] = BlogPost::whereHas('categories', function($q) {
            $q->whereIn('slug', ['cat-a','cat-b']);
        })->get(); 

}
```

Second solution:

In the October CMS backend you can't configure the categoryFilter property of the BlogPosts component with a list of categories. But you can let this property empty for including all categories, and then you can use the exceptCategories property with the list of categories you don't want. exceptCategories admit *a comma separated list of category slugs or variable with such a list of categories you want to exclude*.

```
[blogPosts blogPostsCatACatB]
...
exceptCategories = "cat-c, cat-d, cat-e"
```