# RainLab.Blog Post List: List Sub-Categories under a specific Top-Level Category

Tags: twig, octobercms, octobercms-plugins

I'm working on an October CMS project which use a blog where I need to seperate blog posts in two major categories. When listing blog posts using the RainLab.Blog plugin's Post List component, I need to list categories that are sub-categories under a specific top-level category and exclude other categories.

[image]

In the TWIG template, I want to iterate through and list out the categories that belong to "Birds" and not "Sealife".

In the default Post List component, categories are listed like this:

```
{% for category in post.categories %}
    <a href="{{ category.url }}">{{ category.name }}</a>{% if not loop.last %}, {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

I would like to change this to something like this:

```
{% for category in post.categories %}
    {# if category is a sub-category of "Birds"... #}
        <a href="{{ category.url }}">{{ category.name }}</a>{% if not loop.last %}, {% endif %}
    {# endif #}
{% endfor %}
```

So I would like the post to be listed as "Shorebirds" and "Hummingbirds" but not as "Corals" as this is a category that is not a direct child of "Birds".

I came across [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49952555/how-to-filter-blog-posts-with-multiple-categories-in-octobercms), but it avoids rendering posts that do not match the criteria all together. I still want to fetch and render posts that are in other categories, but only *list the categories if they match*.

Comment: ok so if I am correct you want just a list of categories which is a direct child of the TOP level category of that particular blog, So one info. is needed like how do you define which one is a main TOP level category or are they fixed or it's ok to hardcode them?

Comment: and another question you shared us a screenshot where you are selecting those categories :)

Comment: Correct. I don't want TWIG to output each and every category the current post in the post list has been tagged with, but ONLY if said category has the category "Birds" as a direct parent. It's totally fine if the category "Birds" is hardcoded. I only need to grab it's children dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's totally fine to `hardcode category` then you can simply compare categories parent's `slug` or  `id` to hardcoded value.

> Here I am using the `slug` to compare parent, you can also use `id` it's totally up to you.

```php
{% for category in post.categories %}
    {% set parentCat = category.getParent().first() %}                        
    {% if parentCat.slug == 'birds' %}
    <!-- here we are ^ comparing ^  please replace value as per your need -->
        <a href="{{ category.url }}">{{ category.name }}</a>
        {% if not loop.last %}, {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

now it should only show a `categories` which have a parent category having `given slug`.

if any doubt please comment